# ContextFlyout in RelativePanel does not behave same way as in Grid

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

I'd like to be able to use a ContextFlyout in a RelativePanel for a context menu.  Simple to setup, but right clicking (or long pressing) in blank space in the RelativePanel does not cause the context menu to show.  This in contrast to doing it in a Grid, where a right click works anywhere, even in blank space.

Simple example for showing the difference:

```
<Page
x:Class="ContextMenuTest2.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:ContextMenuTest2"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <StackPanel>
        <RelativePanel BorderThickness="8" BorderBrush="Black" Height="200" Width="200">
            <RelativePanel.ContextFlyout>
                <MenuFlyout>
                    <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Menu Item"/>
                </MenuFlyout>
            </RelativePanel.ContextFlyout>
            <TextBlock Height="auto" Width="auto">Relative Panel</TextBlock>
        </RelativePanel>
        <Grid BorderThickness="8" BorderBrush="Black" Height="200" Width="200">
            <Grid.ContextFlyout>
                <MenuFlyout>
                    <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Menu Item"/>
                </MenuFlyout>
            </Grid.ContextFlyout>
            <TextBlock Height="auto" Width="auto">Grid</TextBlock>
        </Grid>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both `Grid` and `RelativePanel` are layout controls without any background, which is a key to resolve your problem.

When you interact with the area inside the `RelativPanel` and right-click the empty space inside, because the `RelativePanel` has no background, it does not receive the right-click event and it bubbles up. If you try to right-click the `TextBlock` inside the `RelativePanel`, you will see that the right-click event was captured and the context flyout shows up. Similarly when you set the background like this:

```
<RelativePanel Background="Transparent" ...>
```

Even though the result *looks* the same for the user, the background is now a transparent color brush (which is actually fully transparent white) instead of `null`. And that is enough to capture the user input.

The question of why this does not happen in the `Grid` as well surprised me at first, but I then realized the reason in the XAML designer. Both `TextBlock` controls have `Auto` for `Width` and `Height`, but whereas in `RelativePanel` it means the `TextBlock` will cover only the size it really requires, in `Grid` it is the only child and `Grid` will cause it to stretch both vertically and horizontally to fill the panel. So when you click an empty space in `Grid`, you actually interact with the `TextBlock` and the right-click event is captured and the context flyout appears.

Comment: That solved my problem, thanks!  And thanks as well for the supporting explanation, very helpful.

Comment: Happy to help :-) ! Happy coding!